# Why does the six-question limit exist?

Tags: discussion

Perhaps I'm missing the point, but the entire purpose of Stack Overflow seems to revolve around questions being asked, and subsequently answered.

Isn't limiting the number of questions you can ask per day like limiting the number of items a customer can purchase from a store? Seems detrimental to the success of the website.. but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: If you feel the need to ask more than six questions per day, then that's an excellent sign that you need to take a step back and do more research on your own about what you're doing.

Comment: People learn in different ways. Getting some human interaction is, for many people, a hugely more efficient way of learning and understanding than trying to digest lengthy and often cryptic documentation that's often written for seasoned pros alone.

Comment: @lukech - Someone who is unable to learn anything about how to program from reading any books, documentation, or fiddling around on their own--specifically, someone who is unable to learn programming without constantly asking questions of others--is someone who should probably consider a different career.

Comment: «like limiting the number of items a customer can purchase from a store» Sure, and this is actually done for very popular products where the supply is limited, just like good answers on SO.

Answer (score 4):

There are questions and there are questions. We expect questions at SO to show research effort and some careful thought **before** posting the questions.
Therefore, it is reasonable to expect no more than 6 **good** questions a day from a serious user.

On the other hand, people who make no research effort before asking might exploit SO posting dozens of useless, low-quality "questions" jamming the review queues and overloading moderators.

So I guess this 6 question limit is to encourage careful thinking **before** posting, and preventing an overwhelming number of nonsense questions.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but it seems a little over-zealous in practise. It's very easy to come up with a half-dozen legitimate questions over the course of a hard day's work, particularly if learning some new concept, etc.

Comment: 1. There are far more bad questions than good questions being shunted down the drainpipe of SO's review queues, hence a limit is good. 2. If you're learning a new concept, we expect people to do plenty of research on their own and when they're *really stuck*, come here and ask. =)

Comment: @lukech - for ever rule there are exceptions. But in general this is not the case. Serious users do not ask "tons" of questions, but rather contemplate and work hard on the question itself. It is unusual to see a user with 6 GOOD questions in a row.

Comment: @lukech - Even if you *can* come up with 6 good questions every day, you will soon be surprised that there is a monthly limit as well...

Comment: And how many is that?

Comment: @lukech IIRC, it is 50.